# How to fix "pywinauto" not starting a windows application?

Tags: python, windows, pywinauto

I am trying to use python 3.10.11 on windows 10 to start a windows application. The command I am using is

```
from pywinauto.application import Application
path = r"C:\Program Files (x86)\Main_App\SafetyToolbox\ConfigurationRegister.exe"
app = Application(backend='uia').connect(path=path, timeout=300)
```

with the **correct** path. I double checked the path multiple times, and when I double-click on the `exe` file in the File Explorer the application starts without problem.

Why can't I start the application with `pywinauto`?

Answer (score 1):

First you're using method `connect` instead of `start`. :) Second if you start the same path in `cmd.exe`, the result will be the same because of spaces in the path. Please add single or double quotes around the whole path. Like this:

```
from pywinauto.application import Application
path = r"C:\Program Files (x86)\Main_App\SafetyToolbox\ConfigurationRegister.exe"
app = Application(backend='uia').start('"' + path + '"')
```

Comment: Ah I have to use start! Thanks for that. I need to watch more videos on the basic usage - as the "Getting Started Guide" for pywinauto is basically completely useless.